# Cannot import BertModel from transformers

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to import BertModel from transformers, but it fails. This is code I am using

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertForMaskedLM
```

This is the error I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BertModel' from 'transformers'
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed the error. This is the code

```
from transformers.modeling_bert import BertModel, BertForMaskedLM
```

Answer (score 1):

lastest version of transformers have fix this issue. you can use the below command

```py
pip install --upgrade transformers
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, Uninstall transformer and *reinstall* it along with *spacy*.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code too `from transformers import BertModel, BertForMaskedLM`; just make sure your `transformers` is updated.